# setlocale issue using gettext

Tags: php, gettext, setlocale

In my production server (CentOS), `setlocale` seems to require the following format: `en_US`.

Which isn't working for me, since I have 248 countries and 66 languages - the visitor will be able to choose any country, with any language.

Is it possible to be just `en`?

The interesting thing is, that on my local server (MacOSX) it's working fine with `en`.

```
<?php
putenv('LANG=' . $_SESSION['locate']['language']['iso'] . '_' . $_SESSION['locate']['country']['iso']); // I want to use only en, not en_US
setlocale(LC_ALL, $_SESSION['locate']['language']['iso'] . '_' . $_SESSION['locate']['country']['iso']); // I want to use only en, not en_US

bindtextdomain('messages', dirname(__FILE__) . '/locate');

textdomain('messages');

echo gettext('This is a text string!');
?>
```

Comment: Execute the following command here ~/.bashrc

export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8

Comment: Actually, my question was - can I use `en`, instead `en_US`. I want to do this, because, for example, someone may choose language "en" and country "CN", you know?